# the meaning of "as a blessing"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I understand the meaning of "blessing" in this sentence:

> It is a **blessing** that no one got badly hurt.

But I am not sure what it means if it is used this way:

> Not everybody sees permanent access to fast messaging services **as a blessing**.

Comment: Kitty, you don't need the "br" tags, you can use double spaces at the end of sentences instead. I know it's counterintuitive, it took me some time to figure it out too.

Comment: Thank you for your help, CopperKettle. I am still learning how to use the HTML tags in ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Not everybody sees permanent access to fast messaging services as a blessing.

The confusing part of this sentence, I think, is the verb "sees." Here it means "has an opinion of." In a conversation, it might sound like this:

> Alice: "Permanent access to fast messaging services is a blessing."
>   Bob: "I don't see it that way."

Bob is disagreeing with Alice. He's saying "I don't have that opinion." We could turn it around:

> Bob: "Permanent access to fast messaging services is bad."
>   Alice: "I see it as a blessing."

Alice could have said, "No, it's a blessing," but "see it as" emphasizes that it's her opinion, instead of implying that Bob is wrong. It's much more passive and less confrontational.

English speakers often use "see" to mean "believe" or "understand." For example, if you convinced me of something in an argument, I might say, "I see your point." If you explained something to me, I might say, "I see what you mean." (And a common idiom that describes two people in agreement is, "Alice and Bob see eye-to-eye.")

This is my first answer here; I hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 4):

In your first example it means that the odds of someone getting hurt were very high, so God himself must have performed a miracle and prevented anyone from getting hurt.

In your second example, it's used a bit sarcastically. It's an understatement, instead of saying that some people think it's a bit rubbish, the writer is saying that not everyone thinks it's a gift from God.